# Emacs regexp and syntax highlighting

Tags: php, regex, emacs, font-lock

I want to highlight some words (ex. "true", "false"), but only when they are between the tags `<?=` and `?>`.

In the example below I only want to highlight the second "true" keyword:

```
<input checked="true"><?=($i === true ? $foo : $bar)?>
```

Is there any special font-locking mode for this kind of situation?

Comment: BTW, why don't you use PHP mode? It highlights true/false by default.

Comment: I use php-mode for php files only. For templates files (html/php) I am trying to write my own "simple" mode.

Comment: But why? Isn't it simpler to use php mode for those files too if they use php syntax?

Comment: Because I wan't some features that aren't needed in a pure php-mode. For example, synthax highlithing for html tags and attributes are really important. Indentation, by contrast, is not needed or just a simple one like indent-relative. This mode is only developed for "one line php statemements" inside html elements.

Comment: I use the [multiple major modes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MuMaMo) extension which as the name suggests activates multiple modes in the same file at once. So it provides syntax highlight both for the embedded PHP code and for the HTML tags in the same file which sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: I know this mode by I have very often read that their are many problems with it. It is a great mode, but I think that my needs are really smaller and I would like to build a very small and effective mode. I've just read this blog (http://nex-3.com/posts/79-highlighting-ruby-in-haml-mode) which is great, but I would happy to have some clues or links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font lock can call functions too in addition to matching regexps:

> Find text by calling function, and highlight the matches it finds
>   using font-lock-keyword-face.

http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html

Only you need to know Elisp.

Comment: Yes but do you have any link to share ... I know some very basic stuffs in elisp and would like to begin with an example